# Img-fluid doesn't resize the image in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

pretty simple problem. I have a navbar with an image brand and I'm using img-fluid so it will just resize to fit the div instead of specifying a height and width. This way it'll be responsive. The problem is that it doesn't change size at all and it just stretches the navbar out and is huge.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="assets/images/urbane-sleek.png" class="img-fluid"  alt="">
        </a>
      </nav>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 .d-xs-none .d-sm-none">Text...</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">Text...</div>
        
    </div>
```

I've tried setting max-width: 100% and height: auto; in the style attribute and that does nothing. Help?

Answer (score 1):

You still have to tell what is the image size, `img-fluid` just makes it responsive, but it will keep the original size of the picture. Either set the size on the image tag itself:

```
<img src="assets/images/urbane-sleek.svg" class="img-fluid" height="100" width="100" id="exampleImage"alt="">
```

Or add a css rule:

```
<img src="assets/images/urbane-sleek.svg" class="img-fluid" id="exampleImage" alt="">

#exampleImage {
  min-width: 10px;
  max-height: 200px;
  min-width: 10px;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o51tb7w4/6/)